# c# ClickOnce test if updating my application works local

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce, updates

I finished an `c# application` and I'am able to `Publish` it, the problem is that I want to test the `update` function local, one problem: I can't just give in a `folder path`, so I can't `update` from a folder on my local pc. I need to upload the application to a server(website), is there a way to test if the update function is working local on my pc? Or can anybody give me a link to an good tutorial for testing this local?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=test+clickonce+local&aq=f&oq=test+clickonce+local&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j65l3j0.2274&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/local-deployment-of-a-clickonce-application/